# What is this lawn patch called and where can I buy it?

Tags: lawn, lawn-repair

I bought a home and want to fix the lawn in my yard. There are big empty spots in yard without lawn. I was wondering what is the quickest way to get the lawn that will last long? I saw few people in my community have yellow lawn patches like the one in attached picture. What is it called and where can I buy it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like sod. Most nurseries and home/garden centers have it. It comes in rolls of 2x10 around here.